# Spring MVC while configuring web.xml

Tags: spring-mvc

I was trying to configure web.xml for Spring MVC but after that my html page did not run on server it showed "404" The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists. Please help me with this. My project structure and web.xml is as below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yg47Z.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hY55V.png)

Comment: Don't post code as a link to an image. Post it as text, in your question. You're mapping every path ending with .html to the Spring servlet. So a request to Login.html goes to the Spring servlet. So if you don't have any Spring controller configured for /Login.html, a 404 is returned.

Comment: Thanks it helped :)